# How to configure a intranet router to inform its hosts about routes to other subnets?

Tags: networking, router, routing, iptables, forwarding

It sounds a little bit strange, but the current network configuration is, I have two local networks: 192.168.7.0/24 and 192.168.144.0/24. Their gateways are respectively 192.168.7.1 (R1) and 192.168.144.1 (R2). R2 is connected to R1's local network using WLAN, its IP address being 192.168.7.94. R1 is not directly connected to R2's local network (192.168.144.0/24).

R1 is a OpenWRT enabled D-LINK router. R2 is a Linux PC.

There is a static route on R1, that any incoming packets targeting at 192.168.144.0/24 be forwarded to 192.168.7.94. R2 also accepts incoming packets from any interface targeting at 192.168.144.0/24 and forwards them to its interface which is configured as 192.168.144.1.

So far, a host 192.168.7.74 (H3) on 192.168.7.0/24 can access any host on 192.168.144.0/24, because 192.168.7.1 can forward their packets to 192.168.7.94 (R2).

---

The problem is, I found the route table on H3 doesn't have an entry says that any packets  to 192.168.144.0/24 should go to 192.168.7.1 (or the interface connecting to R1). That's okay when H3 is only connected to one network.

However, if H3 is connected to the Internet using LAN, the "default" entry in H3's route table becomes the LAN interface that's connected to the Internet, then all packets to 192.168.144.0/24 are forwarded to the Internet router, which definitely doesn't have access to R2's intranet. Then the issue is, once H3 is connected to the Internet, it no longer has access to 192.168.144.0/24, even if it is still connected to R1's network (192.168.7.0/24).

I would like to know, if it is possible for R1 to "inform" all its hosts to add an entry to their route tables that packets to 192.168.144.0/24 should be sent to 192.168.7.1 (or the interface connecting to R1).

Comment: You have not received any response to your question yet. This may be due to your question being a bit hard to follow. You may want to may want to [edit] your question to be more "to the point", with only the details directly pertaining to your question. Questions that are hard to read or follow often get overlooked. If you need assistance, take a look at ***[ask]***.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out one solution using DHCP.

I added the "Classless Static Route" options (121 and 249) to the DHCP server on the OpenWRT enabled router R1. It looks like:

```
121,24.192.168.144,192.168.7.94
249,24.192.168.144,192.168.7.94
```

The second one (249) is for Microsoft Windows clients, according to what I found on the web. Please refer to this link for configuring these options: https://ercpe.de/blog/advanced-dhcp-options-pushing-static-routes-to-clients

In OpenWRT, I can add these options in the configuration of my LAN network (Network - Interfaces - LAN - Edit - DHCP Server - Advanced Settings - DHCP Options).

After settings these options properly, hosts will be able to receive static routes from the router R1 when they receive their DHCP leases.