# Access across subnets

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

A r7000 nighthawk, running stock hardware (routerA) is connected to a modem/router (modem). There is also a second r7000 nighthawk (router B), using dd-wrt connected via ethernet to a port on routerA.

modem is 192.168.1.1
routerA is 192.168.1.3 and has a DHCP that delivers 192.168.2.x addresses
routerB is plugged into routerA, has a local IP address of 192.168.2.2. Has a DHCP server that delivers 192.168.3.x addresses.

How can I get clients from routerA to see client on routerB and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Setups should mostly happen on router A, because I think your devices connected to B should be able to see devices connected to A (I mean, access using their IP addresses).

Here is a picture for my scenario. It should be similar to yours except for that I have some redundant links in my networks. The PCs, the laptop, and the mobile phones can access each other using IP addresses.

[image: My networks]

Basically, you need to

**If your devices connecting to router A are not connected to any other networks, which means router A is their default gateway.** Let router A know that all traffic to 192.168.3.0/24 should use your router B's "external" IP address (should look like 192.168.2.x) as the gateway. This is doable on most router firmwares (as static routes or forwarding rules), I believe. Below is my OpenWrt router settings for that:

[image: Configure static routes on your router A]

However, when A is not their default gateway, client has no way to know that traffic to 192.168.3.0/24 should go to A - in this case you will need the alternative solution.

Alternatively, you can also let router A's DHCP server tell the clients to configure 192.168.2.x (router B's IP address on subnet A) as the gateway to 192.168.3.0/24. You may want to refer to my previous question at this link: [How to configure a intranet router to inform its hosts about routes to other subnets?](https://superuser.com/questions/1038250/how-to-configure-a-intranet-router-to-inform-its-hosts-about-routes-to-other-sub). However this may not be doable on stock firmwares.

Comment: RouterA connects to the Internet properly.

Comment: @JacobFarkas It doesn't matter what A connects to. I was talking about devices connecting directly to A (hence at the same level with B). If one such device has or potentially may have other gateways at higher priority than A - for example, a laptop connecting to A using Wi-Fi but also connected to ethernet.

Comment: Can I have static routes for each others subnets set up on both routers? Simpler to add firewall rules to pass network traffic on RouterB as it is a dd-wrt box, so I can add access rules for the 192.168.2.x network, but how best to set up Firewall rules on a stock r7000 unit, so that it can accept 192.168.3.x traffic?

Comment: @JacobFarkas I am confused. Where is the 192.168.3.x router connected? How is your original question related to firewall? If it is a separate question you should start a new question.

Comment: This scenario has 3 network devices, modem > routerA > routerB. Modem is 192.168.1.1, routerA (ethernet to modem) is 192.168 1.3. It also serves 192.168.2.x/24. RouterB (ethernet to routerA) is 192.168.2.2 and serves 192.168.3.x addresses. RouterA runs stock r7000, routerB runs dd-wrt. My question was how to best get the 192.168.2.x clients to talk to the 192.168.3.x clients? I added that while I can do static routes on each device for the other device's subnet, and while I can do the fw rules on the dd-wrt device, I am unsure how to do the fw rules on the r7000 stock firmware

Comment: @JacobFarkas May have misunderstood your scenario. Updated the numbers to match your subnet IDs. Basically if you set up static routes, the devices will be inter-accessible on different subnets. Right?

Comment: it may not be possible (I don't see a way) to create a rule that allows 192.168.3.x clients to access the 192.168.2.x subnet using the stock firmware on the r7000. I'm racking my brain for another strategy. routerB runs as a VPN client, and I need to keep its clients on that isolated network so that their traffic goes through VPN. THE SSID on routerB is different from that on routerA. Ideally, router B's DHCP server could broadcast on the same subnet as routerA, but with a smaller pool of addresses. The DHCP server on routerA won't allow it

Comment: @JacobFarkas Are all 192.168.3.0/24 clients connected to router B? Is router B connected to router A? Then why shouldn't there be a rule to allow those clients to access clients in 192.168.2.0/24? This is how most routers work - if you compare 192.168.2.0/24 to the Internet and 192.168.3.0/24 to the intra-net, router B is just a regular router, isn't it?

Comment: @JacobFarkas Maybe you can try to draw some pictures to help readers understand what your problem is exactly.

Comment: @JacobFarkas See my picture. I think you only have the left half and center part of my picture. My wireless router is like your router A, and my forwarding-enabled Linux PC is like your router B. You want device connecting to B and the device connecting to A to access each other, right? It is working with my settings.